# html5 creating a list

Tags: html, css

When I create a list using html5 and css3 it displays like this.

The cast of the movie: Too Big to Fail

- William Hurt as Hank Paulson
- Paul Giamatti as Ben Bernanke
- Billy Crudup as Timothy Geithner
- Edward Asner as Warren Buffet

But I need this bullet point to be displayed right under the "The" in the heading.How can I do it using css3?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a negative margin :

**HTML**

```
The cast of the movie: Too Big to Fail

<ul class="movie-list">
    <li>William Hurt as Hank Paulson</li>
    <li>Paul Giamatti as Ben Bernanke</li>
    <li>Billy Crudup as Timothy Geithner</li>
    <li>Edward Asner as Warren Buffet</li>
</ul>
```

**CSS**

```
.movie-list li {
    margin-left:-15px;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/zQ5bc/1/

Answer (score 0):

You need to adjust padding on `<ul>` element. [example](http://jsfiddle.net/C2Ev3/1/)